# .NET validar si existe una columna en un IDataRecord C#

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un `constructor` que alimento a través de una consulta a BBDD a través de un método que, al ser llamado desde diferentes puntos de la aplicación provocará que el resultado obtenido de la `SELECT` **no** tenga las mismas columnas en todos los casos.

Para que os hagáis una idea, este es el método que me devuelve el objeto que quiero crear:

```
private static SMOrder CreateSMOrderObjectFromDataRecord(IDataRecord record)
{
        return new SMOrder(){
            Society =       (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"],    //no siempre llega
            Division =      (int)record["DIVISION_ID"],   //no siempre llega
            Order =         (string)record["ORDER"],   
            Lang =          (string)record["LANG_ID"],
            Description =   (string)record["DESCRIPTION"] //no siempre llega
        };
    }
```

Con el siguiente código consigo comprobar si el valor que me llega de BBDD está vacío o no antes de asignárselo a mi variable, pero sólo parece funcionar con `strings`:

```
string description = !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)record["DESCRIPTION"].ToString()) ? (string)record["DESCRIPTION"] : null
```

Necesito hacer lo mismo para un valor entero `int` y así aprovechar la llamada al mismo método.

He probado con las siguientes posibilidades:

```
Society = (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"] == null  ? 0 : (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"],
Society = (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"] ? 0 : (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"],
Society = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(record["SOCIETY_ID"].ToString()) ? (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"] : 0,
```

Pero siempre me da `false` ya que **nunca** un entero = `null`.

¿Cómo puedo solventar esto sin tener que modificar la `SELECT`?

---

**EDIT**

El problema con el que me enfrento es que `record["SOCIETY_ID"]` (u otras columnas) no existen dentro de `record` y al hacer la comprobación actual, o el `ToString()` peta y da el siguiente error:
**Detalles de la excepción**: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: SOCIETY_ID.

He probado con los ejemplos de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9788466/5783990) y sus [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788489/5783990) pero sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Has intentado usando (int?)

Comment: Si, de hecho la definición del `constructor`es del tipo `int?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las columnas de registros de la base de datos no son `null` nunca,si no `DBNull`. Para solucionar tu problema,prueba con este código:

```
Society = record["SOCIETY_ID"] == DBNull.Value  ? 0 : (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"]
```

**EDICION**

Vale, te había entendido mal. Para comprobar si existe una columna en un `IDataRecord` debes obtener una lista de columnas (en un diccionario por ejemplo), como por ejemplo usando este metodo de extensión:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetAllNames(this IDataRecord record) {
    var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++) 
    {
        result.Add(record.GetName(i), i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

El modo de usarlo sería asi:

```
if (record.GetAllNames().ContainsKey("SOCIETY_ID"))
{
    Society = (int)record["SOCIETY_ID"];
}
else
{
    Society = 0;
}
```

**Edicion 2**

Otra opción en una sola linea usando `Enumerable.Range` y `Any` tomada de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126411/ado-net-check-if-field-name-exists-on-idatarecord):

```
bool existe = Enumerable.Range(0, record.FieldCount)
                        .Any(x => record.GetName(x) == "SOCIETY_ID")
```

Comment: No va. El problema es que `record["SOCIETY_ID"]` no existe y da el siguiente error: **Detalles de la excepción:** System.IndexOutOfRangeException: SOCIETY_ID

Comment: Te había entendido mal @AXL. Mira mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias. Voy a probarlo y te digo qué tal ;)

Comment: El código la verdad está sin probar. Si te falla comentamelo :)

Comment: no termino de entender el `this`de los parámetros que espera la función `GetAllNames(this IDataRecord record)` ¿para qué se usa?

Comment: Eso es porque el método que te pongo es un [Método de extensión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb383977.aspx). En el enlace se explica mejor. Para que te funcione, simplemente crea en tu proyecto una clase `static` y pega el codigo del método. El `this` toma como parametro lo anterior, por ejemplo en este caso al llamar a `record.GetAllNames()` el parametro `this` se toma de `record`

Comment: @Pikoh [no está demás que copies la respuesta usando LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126411/ado-net-check-if-field-name-exists-on-idatarecord) :)

Comment: @Davlio te refieres a la que usa `Enumerable.Range` y `Any`?

Answer (score 1):

Con el diseño actual tienes dos opciones:

1. Tratar de obtener la posición o el valor del campo por nombre (utilizando `GetOrdinal` o `GetInt32`) y manejar la excepción `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
2. Antes de leer los datos, obtener los nombres de todos los campos contenidos en el `IDataRecord` utilizando `GetName` en un ciclo que vaya desde 0 hasta `FieldCount` y verificar si existe el campo en cuestión.

Sin embargo, considero que deberías cambiar el diseño para que en todos los casos siempre se tengan los mismos campos y en caso de no tener valor que se devuelva `DBNull`, ya que las opciones mencionadas anteriormente tienen un impacto en el desempeño.

Comment: Pues la verdad @Xint0, después de barajar las distintas posibilidades y sus costes y viendo todo el puzzle con + perspectiva, tal vez me convenga + optar por crear un nuevo método que sólo me recoja las columnas que si sé que existen en ese `record`